# How to transfer data to the desired sheet with VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

Excel 2013 with VBA macro.
2 command buttons named `cmdAddDate` and `cmdMove`.
`cmdAddDate` allows to add another sheet coming from a ComBoBox1.
`cmdMove` allows me to transfer data from 2 textbox to Excel Sheet.

My problem is that I don't know what to use so that the data from 2 textbox will move in to the desired sheet.

Currently I'm using a static way of defining where to send data with this code:

```
With Worksheets("June 1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
```

I have a screenshot: [image: Screenshot]

From my example based on screenshot, I want kurt to be move in to the Sheet "June 2"..Please any advise / help will be much appreciated.

Here's my code so far:

```
Private Sub cmdAddDate_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = ComboBox1.Value
End Sub


Private Sub cmdMove_Click()
    With Worksheets("June 1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
        'With UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value
        .Offset(1, 0) = UserForm1.txtName.Value
        .Offset(1, 1) = UserForm1.txtID.Value 
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.Clear

    With ComboBox1
        .AddItem "June 1"
        .AddItem "June 2"
        .AddItem "June 3"
        .AddItem "June 4"
        .AddItem "June 5"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your worksheet name based on the `Value` selected in `ComboBox1`, i.e. change

```
With Worksheets("June 1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
```

to

```
With Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
```

Comment: wow pretty easy huh..I tried to used that code earlier but giving me an error..but right now it's working.Thank you so much.

Comment: @FrozenBlood - My guess is that you had an error before because the user hadn't selected a value, or if the value selected was not the name of an existing worksheet.  (If you haven't already done so in your real code, you should consider adding additional code to test the user input for validity prior to using it.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help..I used this for my simple login system..Thank you so much YowE3k